Publishing a Facebook page
I have just created a primitive Facebook page.
After some huffing and puffing, I managed to get to the point where I'm looking at my page and getting the following message:

This is an unpublished Page


Only you and the people who manage Mellifera can see and manage this Page. You can publish it again anytime in your Page settings. While you're switched into your unpublished Page, do not use it to interact with others on Facebook.

But when I go into Page settings, I can find no way of publishing the blessed thing!
I wonder if anyone can help!
Thanks very much in advance!
Jaime
